# Code optimization for checkboxes in next typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to pass only data to only one checkbox so the code doesn't become redundant.

I've taken these so I can check the max and min value of some API data.

```
const[checkValMax, setCheckValMax]= useState(599);
const[checkValMin, setCheckValMin]= useState(0);
const handleFirstInput= () => {
    if(firstInp){
        setCheckValMin(0); setCheckValMax(599)
    }
    else{
        setCheckValMin(199);  setCheckValMax(599)
    }
}

return (  <div className='flex flex-col gap-2'>
    // this resets the price tags
    <div>
        <label className='text-sm text-gray-400 mr-4'> Reset</label>
        <input className='bg-gray-800 text-gray-400 rounded border border-stone-200 space-x-3' type='checkbox' name='inputfield' onClick={()=>handleReset()} />
    </div>
    // 1st checkbox
    <div>
        <label className='text-sm text-gray-400 mr-4'> {'>'} $1.99</label>
        <input className='bg-gray-800 text-gray-400 rounded border border-stone-200 space-x-3' type='checkbox' name='inputfield' onClick={()=>{setFirstInp(!firstInp);handleFirstInput() }} />
    </div>
    // 2nd checkbox
    <div>
        <label className='text-sm text-gray-400 mr-4'>$2.00 - $2.99</label>
        <input className='bg-gray-800 text-gray-400 rounded border border-stone-200 space-x-3' type='checkbox' name='inputfield' onClick={()=>{setCheckValMin(200); setCheckValMax(299) }}/>
    </div> 
    // 3rd checkbox
    <div>
        <label className='text-sm text-gray-400 mr-4'>$3.00 - $3.99</label>
        <input className='bg-gray-800 text-gray-400 rounded border border-stone-200 space-x-3' type='checkbox' name='inputfield' onClick={()=>{setCheckValMin(300); setCheckValMax(399) }}/>
    </div> 
    // 4th checkbox
    <div>
        <label className='text-sm text-gray-400 mr-4'>$4.00 - $4.99</label>
        <input className='bg-gray-800 text-gray-400 rounded border border-stone-200 space-x-3' type='checkbox' name='inputfield' onClick={()=>{setCheckValMin(400); setCheckValMax(499) }}/>
    </div> 
    // last checkbox
    <div>
        <label className='text-sm text-gray-400 mr-4'> {'<'} $5.00</label>
        <input className='bg-gray-800 text-gray-400 rounded border border-stone-200 space-x-3' type='checkbox' name='inputfield' onClick={()=>{setCheckValMin(0); setCheckValMax(500) }}/>
    </div>
</div> )
```

Is there a way to define 1 checkbox component and pass value to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [checkValMax, setCheckValMax] = useState(599);
  const [checkValMin, setCheckValMin] = useState(0);
  const handleFirstInput = () => {
    if (firstInp) {
      setCheckValMin(0);
      setCheckValMax(599);
    } else {
      setCheckValMin(199);
      setCheckVlMax(599);
    }
  };

    const checkboxes = [
        {
            label: 'Reset',
            onClick: () => handleReset();
        },
        {
            label: ' > $1.99',
            onClick: () => {
                setFirstInp(!firstInp);
                handleFirstInput() 
            }
        },
        // etc...
    ]

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col gap-2'>
        {checkboxes.map(({ label, onClick }) => 
      <div>
        <label className='text-sm text-gray-400 mr-4'>{label}</label>
        <input
          className='bg-gray-800 text-gray-400 rounded border border-stone-200 space-x-3'
          type='checkbox'
          name='inputfield'
          onClick={onClick}
        />
      </div>
        )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```